# Creating new columns with values based on the value in another column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to take the data from an Excel sheet and use SSIS to insert it into a SQL Server database. I have an Excel dataset that looks like this:

```
ID (int) | PromotionOrNot (string) | PromotionOrRegPrice (decimal)
---------+-------------------------+------------------------------
1        |    Promotion            |      14.99
1        |      Not                |      16.99
```

I'm not sure why it was set out like this, but the best I can get to using sort and script transformations (as well as various other methods) in SSIS is this:

```
ID (int) |  RegPrice (decimal) | PromotionPrice (decimal)
---------+---------------------+-------------------------
1        |    0                |      14.99
1        |    16.99            |       0
```

Obviously this isn't good enough, a setup like this is needed:

```
ID | RegPrice | PromotionPrice
---+----------+---------------https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
1  |   16.99  |      14.99
```

Can anyone help me with a way to sort this out? It would be much appreciated. Any other info can be provided as necessary.

Edit: <s>Never mind sorry, I managed to use the Union All transformation with another data flow to sort it out. I'm not sure if this will work for anyone else's problems.</s>

Edit 2: No, I was just being an idiot. All this did was pin the above results to the bottom of the other input to the Union.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Pivot`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select ID, [Not] as RegPrice, Promotion as PromotionPrice
from @T
pivot (
    avg (PromotionOrRegPrice) 
    for PromotionOrNot in ([Promotion],[Not])
) As PivotedData
```

Comment: Sorry I'm still pretty new at this, I assume this is for use with data already in a table. I'm trying to take the data from an excel sheet and use SSIS to insert it into an sql database. Do you know how to use Pivot in the data flow tasks in a similar manner to what you've written here?

Comment: The last time I've had to import data from excel to sql server was over a decade ago. I can't really remember what I did back then.

Comment: This'll still work @AParkInTheWalk, just instead of using an ETL process do a ELT process. Load to a staging table and then use the solution here to transform your data into your production table.

Comment: I'm not certain that's going to work out, as so far I keep getting primary key violations as each ID that is used as the primary key reoccurs.

Comment: In your staging table? I wouldn't bother with a primary key on that.

Comment: Yeah that was a bit stupid but I did figure it out eventually. Still having a couple issues with the specifics of the SQL statement. I need to do a bit more research on pivot.